# Plotting a collection of variables on a grid in R

Tags: r, gridextra

I would like to learn a good way to plot a collection of variables `p`(dataframe columns) into a grid rather than writing out each variable into the grid.arrange function.

```
p <- c()
for (i in 1:length(names(df)) - 1){
  p[i] <- qplot(df[i])
}
grid.arrange(p, ncol = 5)
```

I want a method for: `grid.arrange(p[1], p[2], ..., p[n]`) to plot each graph in a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pl = replicate(5, ggplot(), simplify = FALSE)
grid.arrange(grobs = pl)
```

Note that your strategy could use a few improvements:

- preallocating `p` would be better with `p = vector(length = ncol(df)-1, mode="list")`
- `p[[i]] <-` not `p[i] <-`
- `1:3 - 1` produces `0 1 2`, and `0` isn't a valid index
- it's easier to work with long format data frames (tidy data) in ggplot/R; try `reshape2::melt()` or `tidyr::gather()` and alternatives, so that you can avoid an awkward loop over column names